# Android WebView: why not displaying this particular web page?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I am attempting to load a web page into a webview. **I have tested this with numerous websites for which it works just fine.** Except this particular mobile website for credit card company Capital One. I would like to find out why loading the following url in my webview results in a blank page.

**Edit: 
NOTE1: I am able to load this web page successfully in the native browser.
Note2: I am able to display other SSL sites in my webview successfully.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_totals, container, false);
   CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
   mWebView2 = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
   mWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   mWebView2.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
   mWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
   mWebView2.loadUrl("https://moblprod.capitalone.com/worklight/apps/services/www/EnterpriseMobileBanking/mobilewebapp/default/EnterpriseMobileBanking.html#www/cards/login?redirect=www/cards/accounts");

   return view;
}
```

Comment: while appending u should use the concat method because i guess the url is not rightly formed

Comment: @Terril Thomas  Doesn't make a difference. In fact, I only concatenated using '+' to make the url shorter in the question.

Comment: but still can u try once

Comment: Ok I will edit the question and display it as my actual code...

Comment: Perhaps it is an issue with getting a secure connection with website.  Have you tried a Try/Catch to see if it throwing any exceptions?

Comment: @wyoskibum I have not. However, I have tried several other secure SSL sites which load successfully. I will publish the try catch results shortly.

Comment: @wyoskibum No Exception is being thrown.

Comment: try this link :http://stackoverflow.com/a/8224661/1562755

Comment: @Terril Thomas To no avail as expected. The site does not have any SSL errors.