# Android webview redirect to https url

Tags: android, redirect, https, android-webview

I have a problem with a webview

This code works perfect :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sContext = getApplicationContext();


    WebView webView =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
        }

        ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    Dialog.setTitle(R.string.alerttitle_pleasewait);
                        Dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.alertmsg_loading));
                    Dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    Dialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {                        
              Dialog.dismiss();

         }
         });

         webView.loadUrl("https://....");

}
```

if ı load http url :

webView.loadUrl("http://....");

it works too.
I try load a http url that redirects to https page.
This https page doesnt work.

Comment: What is the LogCat error?

Comment: possible dublicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-https-url)