# Android WebView does not load URL?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have an Android WebView which should load the following URLs:

```
https://buchung.salonmeister.de/ort/301655/menue/#offerId=907601&venueId=301655

https://buchung.salonmeister.de/place/#offer-details-page?id=907599&venueId=301655
```

Here is what I did:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">



    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"></WebView>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleView"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In `onCreateView()`:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String url = // some url
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);

        final TextView titleView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleView);


        mWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
          }
        });

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
          @Override
          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {
              progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              progressBar.setProgress(0);
            } else {
              progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            titleView.setText(title);
          }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

        return v;
}
```

The screen is empty when I start my activity.

**Note: This is not a layout issue. Please do not comment on layout and focus on the real problem.**

**How can I load the above urls in a WebView?**

Edit: Here are the permissions I gave:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Edit:

In my console I get the following:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(84)] "undefined", source: https://buchung.salonmeister.de/place/ (84)

09-13 15:12:33.230 28407-28407/de.test.webviewtest I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught Error: Script error for: widget/venue-menu/mobile/venue-menu-app
09-13 15:12:33.230 28407-28407/de.test.webviewtest I/chromium: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror", source: https://buchung.salonmeister.de/javascript-module/1.162.3/thirdparty/require.2.1.10.js (1)
```

Comment: Have you added `Internet` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml ` ?

Comment: check your parent or outer xml of webview or paste here

Comment: @RohanPawar I updated my post.

Comment: your layout is weird.

Comment: @njzk2 I think this is not a layout issue. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Did you forget to add the fragment to the activity ?

Comment: I am not sure how the webview feels about `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Anyway, you can use Chrome device inspection to debug your webview and see what happens there: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

Comment: What makes you says that it's not loading? It looks like it loads fine but there is some issue with the javascript to create the modal. What happens if you disable javascript?

Comment: @karaokyo When you load the url in mobile Chrome there is no problem. So why is there a problem with the WebView?

Answer (score 7):

The first problem is you have to swap the position of ProgressBar and WebView.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/progressBar"/>
```

The second problem is this line:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
```

Inside a RelativeLayout, you must have the view id declared in advance, so that another view can be layouted above(right, left is the same way) to.

And again is the same line:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
```

Inside a RelativeView, a view can not layout above(or to below, to left to right) to an ID which is generated for nothing.

You do

```
@+id/progressBar
```

the IDE will auto-generate a new ID, this ID is not the same ID of you mean the WebView to layout above to. And in your ProgressBar declaration, you @+id/progressBar again, which it will re-generate another id.

So, your WebView is layouted above to nothing, you can not even see the WebView, it may loads the URLs, and you just can't see it.

Good luck.

Comment: Well, this has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: confile Have you got the solution,i have stuck on the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your URL is https so It's ssl problem.

You can find a solution in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-https-url).

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you override onReceivedSslError() in WebViewClient?

Comment: If you can provide a link to a working code sample I give you the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

if you want you can try to use Indeterminate Progress Bar Example and remove setWebChromeClient
try this code :

```
public class WebViewActivityFragment extends Fragment {

 public WebViewActivityFragment() {
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);

    final String url = "https://buchung.salonmeister.de/ort/301655/menue/#offerId=907601&venueId=301655";//"https://google.com.vn";
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final TextView titleView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }

         @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         progressBar.setProgress(100);
         super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         progressBar.setProgress(0);
         super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    });


    mWebView.loadUrl(url);

    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION. IT DOES NOT WORK!

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: with `setJavaScriptEnabled(false);`, the Url `"https://buchung.salonmeister.de/ort/301655/menue/#offerId=907601&venueId=301655"` can displayed successfully in the WebView.

[image]

```
public class WebViewActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public WebViewActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);

        final String url = "https://buchung.salonmeister.de/ort/301655/menue/#offerId=907601&venueId=301655";//"https://google.com.vn";
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        final TextView titleView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
        WebView mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setProgress(0);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
                titleView.setText(title);
            }


        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

        return v;
    }
}
```

I have used your entire code, here my web view result. I think perhaps that website is not mobile-ready because I tried to open your 2 urls in web browser in my phone the same problem (still loading...)

[image]

Comment: The website is mobile ready try to open it in mobile safari or mobile chrome.

Comment: @confile: yes. I have tried to remove the line `mWebView.setWebChromeClient` and now the webView can load the Urls

Comment: But if I remove ``setWebChromeClient`` how do I get the progress?

Comment: Please wait, I will post my code, now It can load the Url

Comment: @confile: you can see my code with some small changes from your

Comment: Could you please describe what you have changed?

Comment: `mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);`

Comment: Could you please add a screenShot how the loaded page looks like with your solution?

Comment: Please wait until tomorrow because I have no working environment at this moment :-)

Comment: @confile: I added screenshot

Comment: @confile: I have tested 1st Url in some APIs (16,19,21,22), only 19 cannot display content

Comment: Why cannot Version 19 Display The page?

Comment: I don't know, just inform you that :-). Actually it displayed title only, I think that is the textView

Comment: No this does not work setJavaScriptEnabled false is a bad idea.

Comment: You think it's bad idea, but at least it worked in my testing environment. You should check your environment or contact that site's web admin for further check if needed

Comment: Could you please post a link to a demo project I could download. If it works I give you all the reputation.

Comment: Please wait until tomorrow morning, however, I don't need you have to do so.

Comment: I just need you know that I often only post answer when I have tested in my testing environment

Comment: I cannot reproduce your solution. And why should I disable javascript this would break other urls. There must be a better solution.

Comment: Ok, please wait until tomorrow because I have not had my source code right now.

Comment: I would but the bounty ends in 6hours.

Comment: Ah, don't worry, I don't need that reputation :)

Comment: I think there is a awarding period after the 6 hours so I will give you the reps after your example works at my device.

Comment: I have just created a new project with the code in my answer, can display the 1st link (tested in AVD API16). You can download at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HGUM4c0Ywpb1N5SlZLQmVrUlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The screenshot of new project's result in AVD can be view from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HGUM4c0YwpLUxiM1FaQWhjeVU/view?usp=sharing). Goodnight :)

Comment: Okay you have 22hours left for the bounty to win.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your issue :

```
webView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Setting useWideViewPort from the WebView's settings to true fixed the issue.
`WebView#getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`

Answer (score 0):

The following 2 solutions might help you.

> 1. Cross check you have added Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml
>
>    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
> 2. If you are using an emulator then check the internet is working or not. If not then you can try wipe the data of the emulator and check.

[image]