# Android WebView doesn't display site

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I need to display a website in a WebView. I went through almost all possible solution but my WebView doesn't display the site correctly. Following is my code:

```
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading","Please wait...", true);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.site.ru/login");
```

If I copy the URL 'https://www.site.ru/login' in a mobile browser it displays correctly but in Android app when I tried to load same URL in WebView, but it shows progressBar then everything is displayed white and blank in WebView Screen.

UPD:
my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check url its not working ..............

Comment: @sushildlh its example url

Comment: Add Internet permission

Comment: If all other sites are working fine ,then surely issue is with your URL right ?

Comment: @vinoth12594 in manifest i have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: @sushildlh yes, my link is write. Becouse i copy it from dectop brouser, then i check this link in mobile brouser. Only in webView it not work(

Comment: in place of https use http and try.

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-https-url

Comment: @Rah i try use `http` its not work and i saw the link. Advice in this link not help me

Answer (score 2):

First, create a class that extends `WebViewClient` and which is set to ignore SSL errors:

```
// SSL Error Tolerant Web View Client
private class SSLWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
            }

}
```

Then with your web view object, set its web view client to be an instance of the override class:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(
                new SSLWebViewClient();
        );
```

check this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2388#c15)

Comment: thank, i add `@Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
            }` but i have still same problem. And i add `@Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
                Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + error , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }` for check my error, but i have not error

Answer (score 0):

If Logcat is showing errors similar to:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null"
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem'
```

Enable Dom Storage by adding the following:

```
webView.settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

This seems to allow the browser to store a DOM model of the page elements, so that Javascript can perform operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is because unsecure connections or SSL errors, so you need to implement a class that extends SSLWebViewClient class and override onReceivedSslError method and ignore ssl errors likse this :

```
class SSLWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

    override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler?, error: SslError?) {
        handler?.proceed()
    }
}
```

then :

in `onCreate`

```
onCreate() {
    ...
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.webViewClient = SSLWebViewClient()
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
   ...
}
```