# On fetch() nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview, fetch

Here's a WebView which loads a page with triggers a fetch() on a button click. The html is fine and the page is working in the browser. However the WebView does nothing on click.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  var mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview) as WebView
  var webSettings = mWebView.getSettings()
  webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
  webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
  mWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
  mWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com")
}
```

The error in the debugging console in Android Studio is:

> E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed;
> returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200 I/chromium:
> [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch",
> source: https://example.com/ (0)

What is the cause?

Comment: seems like an error in webpage itself, most likely this error shouldn't affect the working of webpage

Comment: example.com has a horrible TLS setup.

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-an-https-url by @robnick. It works in development.

Answer (score 0):

*As mentioned before and for the lack of a better answer:*

I found the answer here: [Android WebView not loading an HTTPS URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-an-https-url) by @robnick. It works in development.