# Android Studio web app opens a blank page for Wordpress website. How to fix?

Tags: java, android, wordpress

This is the MainActivity.java code in my web app that give a blank Wordpress page when I open the app.

It happens only for Wordpress.

Other websites work just fine.

They open as they should.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

The code is below:

```
package com.sdvjuridic.sdv;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.sdvjuridic.wordpress.com/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the result blank or just not as intended? Could you provide an image example?

Comment: its all white. it should give the website as it is (as I see it from a phone in google chrome for mobile)

Comment: The issue is visiting this site throws a NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error, which means the browser won't inherently trust the site. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-an-https-url) for solutions.

Comment: thanks for the link. It is asked 9 years ago, I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

This code is the fix:

```
package com.sdvjuridic.sdv;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.sdvjuridic.wordpress.com/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    // SSL Error Tolerant Web View Client
    private class SSLTolerentWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }

    }
}
```